# Fitting a bounding ellipse around multiple contours CV2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a binary image with multiple contours detected in it using the following code:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
len(contours)
-> 27
```

I take the 5 largest contours and draw them atop of the original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaHvO.png).

My goal is to map the bottom of the pot. The contours help with light, glare, and lack of edges.

I tried drawing a bounding ellipse around the largest contour:

```
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(largest_contours[0])
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(largest_contours[0])
center = (int(x),int(y))
radius = int(radius)
cv2.ellipse(img,ellipse,(255,0,0),5)
```

But the [results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZUCJ.png) are not sufficient.

How would I go about drawing a bounding circle/ellipse around all the contours so that it successfully maps the bottom of the pot?

Comment: Get the convex hull of the contours. Then fit the ellipse to the convex hull.

Answer (score 0):

You will get better results by using an enclosing ellipse that surrounds *all* contours.

But with such a low quality image, with reflections in all directions plus cast shadows, the reliability of this measurement will be very poor.

Comment: Noted, thanks. How would I go about the code for an eclipse that surrounds all the contours? I was only able to create an enclosing ellipse around one contour.